# Transparent code execution before and after Thread/Task/Action/

Tags: c#, multithreading

The point of all this is to run a separate Thread ( can be something similar: Task, Action ) and to log the "start" and the "end", preferably minimizing code impact (changes) and logging being **transparent to the code, just using a different class**.

Recently I decided to inherit from class `System.Threading.Thread` as a way to implement logging for things like "Thread x started." and "Thread x ended." to a file, for debugging.
Since the class is sealed I used composition to add the Thread as a member and call respective function, accessors and all necessary.
I had a simplistic idea of how to do it so I thought something like

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Thread
    {
        private System.Threading.Thread thread;

        //wrap constructor properties methods...
        //...

        public void Start()
        {
                log(thread.name + " start.");
                thread.Start();
                log(thread.name + " end.");
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

Now after all this trouble of wrapping existing functionality (and using the new namespace instead of System.Threading)... this turned out to be bad since this call if I'm not mistaking is from the **calling** Thread and second the "end" does not log. The logging is mainly for debugging and having a non-volatile state of what happened.

EDIT:

Here's a simplified code using Ahmed's answer, which is good, and still ongoing issue is that if the `SimulatedThread` throws an exception the "Ending..." doesn't log for either "MainThread" or "CustomThread".
If the CustomThread abnormally terminates, "Ending..." for "MainThread" and "CustomThread" should be recorded. ( The exception handling is not relevant ). "MainThread" should be bulletproof from "CustomThread".

**Full implementation**

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;

namespace CS_Tests_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Logger.Log("Starting...");
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";
                CustomThread thread = new CustomThread(SimulateThread)
                    {
                        Name = "CustomThread",
                    };
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log("Cought exception:" + ex.ToString());
            }
            Logger.Log("Ending...");
        }

        private static void SimulateThread()
        {
            Logger.Log("Running...");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            throw new Exception("Test Exception");
        }
    }

    public static class Logger
    {
        public static void Log(String message)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " Thread.CurrentThread.Name is NULL -> " + message);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " -> " + message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomThread
    {
        public Thread threadInstance { get; private set; }
        public CustomThread(ThreadStart threadStart)
        {
            threadInstance = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Logger.Log("Starting...");
                threadStart();
                Logger.Log("Ending...");
            });
        }

        public string Name { get { return threadInstance.Name; } set { threadInstance.Name = value; } }

        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public void Join()
        {
            threadInstance.Join();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            threadInstance.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can switch from from Threads to [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), Tasks are not sealed so you could create a derived class. That way you don't need to use the decorator pattern and you can use the LoggedTask class as a drop in replacement, you only need to replace the constructor/factory.

Comment: About edit: Exceptions thrown from inside threads are _not_ catched by the calling threads. You may catch exception thrown from `threadStart();` as 
`Logger.Log("Starting..."); 
try { threadStart(); } 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ Logger.Log(...); } Logger.Log("Ending..."); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate logging in the `ThreadStart` delegate:

```
public class Logger{
    public void Log(String message){
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class CustomThread {
    public Thread ThreadInst { get; private set; }
    public Logger logger = new Logger();
    public CustomThread(ThreadStart threadStart) {
        ThreadInst = new Thread(() =>
        {
            logger.Log(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " Starting...");
            threadStart();
            logger.Log(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " Ending...");
        });
    }
    public void Start() { ThreadInst.Start(); }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new CustomThread(() => Thread.Sleep(2000)).Start();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Added catching and logging exceptions:

```
    public CustomThread(ThreadStart threadStart) {
        ThreadInst = new Thread(() =>
        {
            logger.Log(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " Starting...");
            try {
                threadStart();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.Log("Error in thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + ex.Message);
            }
            logger.Log(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " Ending...");
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried variations on your answer and it goes bad each time.
"Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart." exception occurs in the Start wrapper when calling the thread.Start(). In the constructors, in the lambda I put thread.Start();. Alternatively I tried with this.Start() same exception

Comment: I edited the question to include a complete implementation, the problem with thread ending abnormally seems to still be present and the main thread seems to get the problem, fact which I don't fully understand why.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, this seems to do fine in common cases, I did not find any forcefully way to end a thread, only loading in a different AppDomain and unloading the domain, not commonly used.
I suggest you use exception.ToString() instead of exception.Message, as it has StackTrace associated and saves a lot on debugging time.
Keep up the good work.